# react-native-webrtc/RTCView.js Attempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'

Tags: react-native, expo

Hey guys I'm using Expo 40 SDK minimal Setup.
And I'm trying to use a library called react-native-webrtc so whenever I try I get an error

So whenever I do an import of any kind

```
import {
  RTCPeerConnection, RTCIceCandidate, RTCSessionDescription, RTCView, MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack, mediaDevices, registerGlobals
} from 'react-native-webrtc';
```

This happen

```
react-native-webrtc/RTCView.js Attempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I navigate to the ios folder and I changed inside PodFile

It was

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

I make it

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

I run pod install

And then I did npm run ios and it solved it was because of the ios version => 11.0.